# PHP - Apostrophe and Double quotes on echo

Tags: php, echo, double-quotes, apostrophe

```
echo '<meta property="article:published_time" content="<?php echo htmlentities($datePublished, \ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", false); ?>">';
```

result: `<meta property="article:published_time" content="<?php echo htmlentities($datePublished, \ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", false); ?>">` And i get `">` printed above the navbar

I know that it's because of the double quotes that starts on `content="`, but i need to put the `UTF-8` on the code line.

I cant put `""` and i can't put `''`, so what i do? There's a way to `echo` this?

Comment: using  a \ before a " will cancel it out. And your already in PHP so no need for the <?php echo again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of backslashes (`\`) to escape your quotes, however, I would recommend separating this out into three 'conjoined' echo statements (separated with `.`); one for the start of the HTML `<meta>`, one for the `htmlentities()`, and one for the end of the `<meta>`:

```
echo '<meta property="article:published_time" content="' .
htmlentities($datePublished, \ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", false) . 
'">';
```

Or on one line:

```
echo '<meta property="article:published_time" content="' . htmlentities($datePublished, \ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", false) . '">';
```

This will output:

```
<meta property="article:published_time" content="SOME_DATE">
```

Comment: I saw that your "Top tags" is html, i have one question, would be there a problem if i have a `meta tag` on this way `<meta><meta>` together on the same line?

Comment: The 'closing' component I was referring to was simply the `>` in `<meta>`. Having said that, it's absolutely fine to have `<meta ... ><meta ... >` on the same line; the `<meta>` tag is an [**empty (void element)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element), so it essentially 'self-closes'. You won't have a problem in doing this... but it's generally 'nicer' to have them separated out onto new lines. Consider appending [**`PHP_EOL`**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) to your `echo` statement :)